# marketo throttle outgoing emails

Tags: email, marketo, throttling

Setting up some emails in Marketo (only to a client list where people opted-in).

I have about 2700 contacts after filtering them, but I don't want to send out 2700 emails at once.  I want to send out about 100 per day.

The reason is that the sales team will quickly get overwhelmed if we send out 2700 emails, even if we only get a low percentage of responses.

Ideally, Marketo would have an option to "quit after X emails".

I know there's a random sample option, which I can set to 4%, but I'm using a smart list (actually a smart list where the contacts aren't in another smart list), and the random sample only works in a regular list to build it.

It's not really an option to create 20 lists and run one each day, even using random sample of 5%.  Even if it was an option, this email is intended to run for at least several months as it slowly picks up new contacts.

Has anyone found a workaround for this need?  We can't be the only ones who have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use 'random sample' combined with 'run once' in the Schedule tab. Then set a recurring schedule so the Smart Campaign runs daily. Every day it will send the email to 4% of your Smart List, but excluding the people who already received the email. You can only set it to a percentage, not to an absolute number, so the absolute number of emails that goes out every day will vary on the smart list size. Periodically, you probably want to adjust the percentage so you can optimize the total number of emails that go out daily.

Comment: Thanks Jep.  I know about the random sample option but this is actually for someone else, and I'm not going to be available to adjust that percentage.  I was really hoping that someone knew a better technique.  Thank you though.

Comment: How do you set it to not skip the people it skipped the previous day?  I have a smart list of 3000 people.  I set it to 4% and it sent out 4%.  The second day it found 2 and skipped them because 4% of 2 is 0, even though the rest of the 3000 people never got the email the previous day.